# Conectar ao banco de dados da LAN

Tags: docker

Tenho a seguinte rede:

Gateway padrão -> 192.168.1.1

Host -> 192.168.1.2

Banco de dados (MySQL) -> 192.168.1.3

Gerei um container usando o docker-compose.yml com a seguinte configuração

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  php53:
    image: bylexus/apache-php53
    container_name: php53
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
    ports:
      - 80:80
    network_mode: bridge
```

Gostaria que, as aplicações dentro do meu container, acessassem o banco da minha rede local: 192.168.1.3. Ao dar `docker container inspect php53`, ele traz o `Gateway: 172.17.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Como seu `db` já existe no endereço informado `192.168.1.3`, e seu propósito é acessar essa base de dentro do `container` basta alterar a linha

`network_mode: bridge` para `network_mode: host`.

fonte: [Igor DevOps](https://www.linkedin.com/in/igor-gevaerd/)